# Get previous week number from a given Year and Week Number

Tags: sql

How can you get the previous Week Number (and year number) from a given Year and Week Number?

e.g.

```
declare @year int = 2014;
declare @week int = 53;
```

I want to get 2014 and 52.

Comment: `@year = if @week > 1 then @year else @year - 1 end` `@week = if @week = 1 then 53 else @week - 1 end` ??

Comment: Which RDBMS you use ? What do you EXACTLY want to do ? Because as the question is stated, i could be tempted to answer @week - 1 ;) (of course if doesn't work for week 1...).

Answer (score 0):

Like @AFract mentioned, depending on what RDBMS you are using, you could do this.

```
DECLARE @year int;
DECLARE @week int;
DECLARE @date datetime;

SET @year = 2014;
SET @week = 53;
SET @date = '01/01/' + CAST ( @year AS varchar ) ;
SET @date = DATEADD ( week , @week - 2 , @date ) ;

SELECT DATEPART ( year , @date ) AS 'Year' ,
       DATEPART ( week , @date ) AS 'Week';
```

Comment: Thanks @austin, your answer is almost there, but the years 2000, 2028, 2056, 2084 ... all have 54 weeks.  The RDBMS I am using is  Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: Sorry about the late reply, but something similar to the edited code may work for you